# Magento 2 disabling payment module bug

Tags: magento2, event-observer, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

```
This is my observer. Works fine but condition if(h = 20) not working     


   <?php

        namespace send\sms\Observer;

        use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
        use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

        class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
        {


         public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
            {

         $h =20;

      if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="creditss" ){

                    $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();

              if($h = 10) {    
                       $checkResult->setData('is_available', false);
                        }
                  }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please explain bit more?

Comment: I need to disable custom payment method depending on some conditions. A disabling function is working but the condition if($h= 10)  is not working.

Comment: That's because you have set $h=20 at the beginning of your function. So it wont enter in to the condition if($h=10) .  Please correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: wherever I give the condition is not working

Comment: do you know if your observer / function being called at all ? try to print the value of $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode(); and exit;

Comment: Simply put some die('here') function inside the place you want to test, and check whether it is hitting or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

$paymeth = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();

if($paymeth == "creditss")
{
    $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
}

$h = 0; //you can give your condition here

switch($h){
   case 0:
       $checkResult->setData('is_available', true);
   break;
   case 1:
       $checkResult->setData('is_available', false);
   break;        
}
```